# sending dgram messages between big and little endien with blowfish

Tags: c++, endianness, blowfish

I have working code to send dgram messages between computers, but I'm trying to encrypt them with Blowfish.  It works fine when I'm trying to send a message between two little endien machines, but when I try sending little endien to big (or the other way around), it doesn't decrypt correctly.

Question 1: Does sendto() convert my message to network byte ordering before sending it?

Question 2: Is this an issue with decrypting my message or is it elsewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. No it doesn't.
2. Your blowfish code is likely not handling endianness properly, this could be encryption, decryption, or both. Without code we can't say.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are encoding integer data in
>   the messages sent through the socket,
>   you should convert this to network
>   byte order too. If you don't do this,
>   your program may fail when running on
>   or talking to other kinds of machines.

from GNU document. http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Byte-Order.html